# How can I connect to a SQLite server with python from a remote location?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to know if I can host a SQLite server and then use python to connect to it remotely.

Thanks,
Colin

Comment: What did you search for "SQLite server" reveal?

Comment: I didn't. I wanted a way to store data remotely, and SQLite came to my mind, because I know a little bit about it compared to literally anything else.

Comment: You can mount the file over network and there were some solutions to provide network access to SQLite, but that's definitely not the intended use case. Perhaps it would be better to use a proper SQL server like PostgreSQL or MariaDB

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is not an actual DB Server Application in the classical sense. It is a "passive" data store on the file system. You could simply connect to whichever remote server has the SQLite file on it and FTP (or scp) it down and then use Python to connect to it using some SQLite driver.

> Because an SQLite database is a single compact file in a well-defined cross-platform format, it is often used as a container for transferring content from one system to another. The sender gathers content into an SQLite database file, transfers that one file to the receiver, then the receiver uses SQL to extract the content as needed.

Source: https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html